# Every time I modify something on my android studio project git hub is full of changes

Tags: android, git, github, flutter

Every time I modify something on my Android studio project (flutter), on GitHub I have more than 300 changes, more or less all around the 'build/" repository of my project.

Also, I don't know if it's relevant, but the 'build/' folder on android studio is highlighted in yellow.

[image: --> on the comment below there are a few picture to better understand the problem]

Comment: Hi, is your build/ repository listed in your .gitignore file ? and is your .gitignore file in your git reposiroty ?

Comment: ![build folder 'error'](https://i.ibb.co/WfSTsXX/build.png)

![android studio](https://i.ibb.co/sVhRrvz/androidstudio.png)

Comment: upload here your .gitignore file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.gitignore` file to your repository.

Check out https://github.com/github/gitignore, it contains `Android.gitignore` which I suggest you download, rename and add to your repo.

Since you already committed the build artifacts into repo you will have to manually remove them. It may only the `build/` folder but there may be other files. To remove the build directory you can use `git rm`.

The procedure could be:

1. Download [Android.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore).
2. Rename it `.gitignore` and copy it to your repo.
3. `git rm --cached build`
4. Commit with a message like 'Adding .gitignore, deleting build directory'.
5. Push

From now on the list of modified files in your commits should not contain files in the build directory.

You may need to repeat deleting of more build artifacts.

---

## New repo option

Another option is to start a brand new repo, copy `.gitignore` there and copy your existing repo **without** the `.git` folder to the new repo.

In this option the build artifacts, including the build folder will not become part of your repo so you don't have to delete them.

With this option you will loose commit history.

Comment: I can't add all of them, literally. I've tried but they are too much so they compleatly fill the gitignore file.

Comment: look at the pictures in my comment

Comment: @MartinaSasso you just need to add the folder name with "/" (for example `/build`) to your `.gitignore` file, all files inside the folder will be ignored

Comment: Don't add individual files. Add the whole folder. This is covered by line 21 in [Android.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore#L21)